# Unity Scene Corrupted?

Tags: unity-game-engine, corruption

I'm working on a Unity game in school and it was working fine until a few days ago when the project would not open. I had left my project open after I left the class, and the computer was shut off with play mode still on. I tried renewing my license, restarting the computer, and deleting the UnityLockFile. The project will start launching, but instantly quit after it gets to about 10%. I copied all the assets into a new project, and it opened, but as soon as I tried importing the scene, Unity crashed, and I could no longer open the project. Is the scene corrupted? Is there a way I can fix it?

Comment: Try deleting Library folder, unity will reconstruct it if missing, as long as none of your assets are corrupt this should clear the cache, force a reimport and generally clean your project

Comment: I tried this and the project still doesn't load. It doesn't crash, but the progress bar freezes at about 10%.